# Does it make sense to version Django projects?

Tags: django

Usually a Django project represents a single website. If it is constantly updated, does it make sense to have versions for the project? When might versioning be useful?

P.S. I am asking not about version control, but about numbering each version like "1.0.5"

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like an exam question

Comment: Just a philosophical question :)

Comment: use git-flow or something similar to track versions and releases. It's your code that has versions, not your website.

Answer (score 3):

Like pointed out in a comment by @Timmy O'Mahony, git-flow or hg-flow do that. The problem with number versions is that it gets very complicated very fast in the development process. They are definitely useful when you ship a product/web-site because then it is very simple for the end-users to compare versions. However in development, you might work on your project in stages - development, testing, staging, and production phases. So introducing numbering version system is going to complicate the process.

Imagine you work on something for v1.0. Then it gets pushes to testing, and then staging phases. Meanwhile you could be working on a new feature for v1.1. However then in staging for v1.0, somebody finds a bug. So then since you are working on v1.1, is that bug fix going to count towards v1.1 or v1.0. Remember that 1.0 hasn't shipped yet...

As you can see it can get very confusing so a better way to work is to follow git-flow type workflow where each branch has its revisions which if need to be can be used to reference to some code changes instead of version numbers.